# Shopify Python API how to retrieve customer's all order

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I see there's an API for shopify to retrieve all orders of an customer by

/admin/api/2020-07/customers/{customer_id}/orders.json

Is there any corresponding in shopify_python_api that I can use? If not, how can I send this API with verification?

Comment: Form [Here](https://shopify.dev/tools/libraries/admin-api). you check the python official library and start building step by step.

Comment: remember that by default you can only use orders from last 30 days

Answer (score 0):

`customer_id` is an acceptable argument to the `Order.find()` method. You can use it like this:

```
import shopify

shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site("https://example-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04")
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_user(API_KEY)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_password(PASSWORD)

orders = shopify.Order.find(customer_id=CUSTOMER_ID, status='any')
```

This plays nicely with the rest of the [filter arguments to the Order endpoint](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2021-01). If you don't include the `status` argument, the API only includes `open` orders by default.